# How to display image using arrays and PictureBoxes

Tags: c#, image

This is suppose to be a matching game using PictureBox, but I keep getting an error of not being able to implicitly convert type '`object`' to '`System.Drawing.Image`'. And I don't know how to continue from there.

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList images = new ArrayList();
    {
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG1.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG2.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG3.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG4.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG5.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG6.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG7.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG8.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG9.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG10.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG11.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG12.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG13.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG14.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG15.png"));
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\MGG16.png"));
    }

    Random r = new Random();

    A1.Image = images[0];
}
```

Comment: Please update your title to tell people what your question is about

Comment: This is a good place to use for loop.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast the object:

```
A1.Image = images[0] as Image;
```

This is because `ArrayList` is weakly typed, meaning that `images[i]` will return an `object`. Casting it with `images[i] as Image` will "turn" this object into its proper type, so that the assignment `A1.Image = ...`, which expects an object of type `Image` will work.

Comment: Maybe post an explanation so that OP understands his mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use strongly-types collection like List<~> (also used loop to add images):

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

    for (int i=1; i <= 16; i++)
        images.Add(Image.FromFile(String.Format(@"{0}\MGG{1}.png",Application.StartupPath,i);
    Random r = new Random();    
    A1.Image = images[r.Next(images.Count)];
}
```

Comment: but the thing is i want to randomize the placement of the images

Comment: The image isn't appearing for some reason